# Extracting value for different url causes error

Tags: php, curl

My initial script for finding the price on flipkart for the url http://www.flipkart.com/moto-g-2nd-gen/p/itme6g3wferghmv3 works perfectly but when i go to find the price for the url http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-core-2-sm-g355hzwdins/p/itmdy3h6qhgz2phv the script gives error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in
>   C:\Users\Abhishek\Desktop\editor\request\main.php on line 18

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$url="http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-core-2-sm-g355hzwdins/p/itmdy3h6qhgz2phv";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
$pagebody=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html($pagebody);

foreach($html->find('.selling-price') as $e)
    echo $e->outertext . '<br>';

    ?>
```

Comment: This means `str_get_html` got an error, so it returned `false`.

Comment: You blindly assume that this `$html = str_get_html($pagebody);` works, you do not do any error checking at all and blindly rely on `$html` being an object, which it most likely is not. Most likely `$pagebody` does not contain what you expect, since again, when you fill it, you do not error checking at all to make sure your `curl` request worked and delivered a usable result.